# SQL delete a category if category is empty

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a trouble, i have a Category with products. My question is how can i remove a category from Database if category is empty and have no products.

My code:

```
$sql = "DELETE 
FROM category AS a 
INNER JOIN products AS b 
ON a.cat_id = b.cat_id 
WHERE a.user_id = ? 
AND a.cat_id = ? LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM category AS a 
Where a.cat_id = ?
And not exists(
 Select 1
 From products p
 Where p.cat_id = a.cat_id
);
```

This query matches the cat I'd on the bind variable and filters out those that have a corresponding product.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the `not exists` operator to look for the categories that are [not] in the `products` table:

```
DELETE 
FROM   category c
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   products p
                   WHERE  c.cat_id = p.cat_id);
```